# Scraping webdata from a website that loads data in a streaming fashion

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to scrape some data off of the FEC.gov website using python for a project of mine. Normally I use python `mechanize` and `beautifulsoup` to do the scraping.

I've been able to figure out most of the issues but can't seem to get around a problem. It seems like the data is streamed into the table and mechanize.Browser() just stops listening.

So here's the issue:
If you visit http://query.nictusa.com/cgi-bin/can_ind/2011_P80003338/1/A ... you get the first 500 contributors whose last name starts with A and have given money to candidate P80003338 ... however, if you use browser.open() at that url all you get is the first ~5 rows.

I'm guessing its because mechanize isn't letting the page fully load before the `.read()` is executed. I tried putting a `time.sleep(10)` between the `.open()` and `.read()` but that didn't make much difference.

And I checked, there's no javascript or AJAX in the website (or at least none are visible when you use the 'view-source'). SO I don't think its a javascript issue.

Any thoughts or suggestions? I could use selenium or something similar but that's something that I'm trying to avoid.

-Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an html parser like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) with [xpath expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

I tried

```
>>> import lxml.html as lh
>>> data = lh.parse('http://query.nictusa.com/cgi-bin/can_ind/2011_P80003338/1/A')
>>> name = data.xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tr[5]/td[1]/a/text()')
>>> name
[' AABY, TRYGVE']
>>> name = data.xpath('//table[2]/*/td[1]/a/text()')
>>> len(name)
500
>>> name[499]
' AHMED, ASHFAQ'
>>>
```

Similarly, you can create `xpath expression` of your choice to work with.

Comment: Can you parse all 500 names out of that request? When I tried I only got the first ~10 rows.

Comment: I tried this xpath `data.xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tr[502]/td[1]/a/text()')` and the output was `name = [' AHMED, ASHFAQ']` which i believe is the last name on the page you mentioned.

Comment: Huh ... I wonder why this parser waits for the whole page to load while `mechanize` dumps early ... but it works just fine now, thanks :)

Comment: @JudoWill: if you find out the answer let me know.

Comment: @JudoWill: If you take a look at `network tab` under `chrome developer tools` the first `GET` request takes around `44.28s` which may be the case why mechanize is not able to render the complete web page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `mechanize`, why don't you use something like `requests`?